# Application Template - Installing custom theme and keystrokes from the __init__.py

Tags: scripting, customization

I am happy to report that [Application Templates](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/app_templates.html#application-templates) are back in action as of yesterday. So this brings my question:
How to code the `__init__.py` script to launch my custom theme colors with Blender? (theme.xml)

Also, I have 2 very simple addons which work with custom shortcut keys. 
How can I add the **shortcut keys** on my application template as well as the **addons** themselves?

Also, how can I add my custom .py addons to work in the same template? What's the correct folder hierarchy before packing it into a .zip?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I'm not against the new 'application-template' tag, but in general, please use existing tags. Tag suggestions could be made on https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions where it can be discussed as to whether a new tag is needed.

Comment: Why don't you want to set Blender preferences themes? Is there a custom theme not available that you are trying to launch?

Comment: yes. Application template = custom theme, custom shortcuts, custom addons.

Comment: No add-on is needed, I made my theme changing colors in Prefs. One question at a time, please. Doesn't the add-on have a documentation?

Comment: You are aware of how application templates work, right Lukasz-40sth?

Comment: Why does this have a -180pts in the community?